# Observed and expected Fisher information of a Bernoulli Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning

If $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p$, the probability mass function is given by

$$
f(k) = p^k(1-p)^{1-k}
$$

and the loglikelihood, $\ell(p)$, is given by

$$
\ell(p) = \log(p)\sum \limits_{i=1}^n k_i + \log(1-p)\left(n-\sum_{i=1}^nk_i\right).
$$

Taking the first derivative with respect to $p$ we get the score function $s(p)$

$$
s(p) = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{i=1}^n k _i - \frac{1}{1-p}\left(n - \sum_{i=1}^n k_i \right)
$$

setting this to 0 and solving it for $p$, we get $\hat{p}_{ml}$

$$
\hat{p}_{ml} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nk_i.
$$

I keep having problems to find the Fisher information, which is the negative second derivate of $s(p)$ and according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) should be:

$$
F(p) = \frac{1}{p(1-p)}
$$

Comment: How far did you get in doing this? It should actually be $F(p) = \frac{n}{p(1-p)}$, however in the case that n=1, you'll of course get $\frac{1}{p(1-p)}$ as the wikipedia page says. The other thing to remember is to replace $\sum k_i$ with the expected information - i.e. $np$. Hopefully that should help you since it seems like you understand the concepts well enough. If you still want help though leave a comment and I'll put in a full solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the hint $\sum k_i = np$ helped me to solve it!